# Ajax Data Posting Getting Error

Tags: php, json, ajax

I saw a form to load data from database, i decode all form ajax code but when i see a new thing inside the form. i don't know what it's mean. Please My Image for more details.

The code something look like that.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "/user/setting/template-action",
    data: {
        _act: "load",
        _tname: tempname,
        _json : $.now() //Here i don't know what is the use of $.now() and how post and verify same value into my php code HOW...!
    }
});
```

**$.now()** how to verify same value into php code
[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg40v.png)

Comment: $.now is used to return a number representing the current time. For more information checkout API Docs for jQuery:: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.now/

Comment: But to i confirm value into my php code

Comment: isnt that should be `method:post` instead of `type:post` there? I think this is just being sent as a `GET` request

Comment: @techie_28 type is an alias for method

Comment: @techie_28 An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

Comment: but what is use of this value...?

Comment: @DeepakSaini why do people buy a watch ?

Comment: @DeepakSaini the answer is in the forst comment of HaRdik Kaji

Comment: hahahaha that is good one\

Comment: @DeepakSaini you havent mentioned the error it is causing.

Comment: @HaRdikKaji  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as per Jquery's documentation $.now is a integer containing the unix timestamp.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.now/

in php this value is represent with `time();`